# R: Iterating Over the List

Tags: r, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement following algorithm in R:

```
Iterate(Cell: top)
    While (top != null)
        Print top.Value
        top = top.Next
    End While
End Iterate
```

Basically, given a list, the algorithm should break as soon as it hits 'null' even when the list is not over.

```
myls<-list('africa','america south','asia','antarctica','australasia',NULL,'europe','america north')
```

I had to add a for loop for using is.null() function, but following code is disaster and I need your help to fix it.

```
Cell <- function(top) {
  #This algorithm examines every cell in the linked list, so if the list contains N cells,
  #it has run time O(N).
  for (i in 1:length(top)){
    while(is.null(top[[i]]) !=TRUE){
      print(top)
      top = next(top)
    }
  }
}
```

You may run this function using:

```
Cell(myls)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close but there is no need to use `for(...)` in this
construction.

```
Cell <- function(top){
    i = 1
    while(i <= length(top) && !is.null(top[[i]])){
        print(top[[i]])
        i = i + 1
    }
}
```

As you see I've added one extra condition to the `while` loop: `i <= length(top)` this is to make sure you don't go beyond the length of the
list in case there no null items.

However you can use a `for` loop with this construction:

```
Cell <- function(top){
    for(i in 1:length(top)){
        if(is.null(top[[i]])) break
        print(top[[i]])
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use this code without a `for`/`while` construction:

```
myls[1:(which(sapply(myls, is.null))[1]-1)]
```

Comment: Wonderful placement of break in second solution. Great work Johan, thank you for sharing all three.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: It runs one by one for all the values in myls and prints them but If it encounters NULL value it breaks.

```
for (val in myls) {
  if (is.null(val)){
   break
  }
  print(val)
}
```

Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Thank you G.arima.